# How can I solve Symfony QueryBuilder Query Error

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, full-text-search, query-builder

I want to use [tsvector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-textsearch.html) for full text search.
I have the query:

```
$queryBuilder->select('c')
  ->from(Campaign::class, 'c', 'c.id')
  ->where('c.user_id = :user_id AND c.tsv @@ to_tsquery(\'english\', \':vector\')')
  ->setParameter('user_id', $userEntity->getId())
  ->setParameter('vector', $request->get('s'))
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult()
```

Result:

```
Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '@'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First of all, I believe you have a mistake with quotes in "->where('c.user_id = :user_id AND c.tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', \':vector\')')" - single quote before "english" ends string and continues with php script. Second, have you configured your connection to use pdo_pgsql driver in Doctrine configuration (as you are using PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Updated. Yes of the connection configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

I believe Doctrine does not have such lexem by default. What you can do is create a **custom type**. Check documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types

Here's also an example of **tsvector** on git:
https://gist.github.com/darklow/3129096